# Go To Definition (Ctrl + Click) in VS Code v1.45.1 with Go v1.14.1 and Ubuntu 20.04 not working

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04

I tried everything mentioned in below link

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/3072

I updated `godef` as suggested and installed `gopls`, but nothing worked for me. Anyone facing a similar issue?

Comment: you better route to `github.com/golang/vscode-go` and fill the issue.

Comment: The issue is already filled and closed at github.com/microsoft/vscode-go, that's why I refrain adding another one

Comment: But I found what's wrong. It turned out that I had another know_host file called .known_host.old  in ~/.ssh which was giving authenticity can't be established message and that requires user input as `yes` . Removed that .known_host.old and it worked. The `gopls` depends on fetch from the repo, that's the reason it was not working.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue using Go 1.16.8.

Use Alt + Click

Answer (score 2):

I just got the same issue, with VSCode 1.66.2 and vscode-go 0.33. (May 2022)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click stopped working, and was replaced with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Click.

To restore the usual behavior:

- open the settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)
- type multi cursor mod
- switch from `ctrlCmd` to `alt`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer may vary based on what OS you're running, but what worked for me in WSL2 (Linux) was deleting the package rogpeppe under go>package>mod>github.com within VS Code and reinstalling it by running the following command `go get -v github.com/rogpeppe/godef`